# Significance test for randomly generated task

Tags: statistical-significance

I have conducted an empirical study as part of my master thesis. Each test subject was asked to find 10 cards (one at a time, without knowing what the next card was) among 50 cards divided into 10 piles. Because of different reasons did I chose to shuffle all cards for each subject, and my hypothesis is that this had ***no significant*** affect on the completion time.

How I can test if the randomly shuffled piles affected the result?

This is how each subjects cards were randomly put, and what completion time it resulted in:

```
          |--------------------------- PILE ----------------------------|
          |   1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10   |            
|-SUBJECT-|-------------------------------------------------------------|--- SEC --|
|    1    |   1     1     1     0     2     1     2     0     1     1   |    171   |
|    2    |   0     1     1     2     1     2     0     2     1     0   |     78   |
|    3    |   1     1     0     3     0     1     0     1     2     1   |    141   |
|    4    |   1     1     2     1     2     0     0     1     1     1   |    122   |
|    5    |   2     1     2     0     1     0     0     0     4     0   |    227   |
|    6    |   2     0     1     1     0     0     2     2     1     1   |    100   |
|    7    |   1     2     2     0     0     0     2     1     2     0   |    148   |
|    8    |   1     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     2   |    113   |
|    9    |   0     2     0     0     2     2     0     1     1     2   |    156   |
|   10    |   1     0     2     1     1     1     0     1     1     2   |    130   |
|   11    |   0     2     3     0     1     2     0     1     1     0   |    112   |
|   12    |   1     1     2     1     1     0     1     1     2     0   |    208   |
|   13    |   1     0     2     0     0     1     1     1     2     2   |    105   |
|   14    |   1     0     1     0     1     2     2     1     2     0   |    216   |
|---------|-------------------------------------------------------------|----------|
```

*Each number in the table represents how many cards were "hidden" in that pile*

I believe the randomness *could* affect the result, if for example all 10 cards were put in the first two piles a test subject tried. However, my gut feeling tells me it had no significant affect, but I would like to write that I actually have verified this.

Answer (score 2):

Am I correct that you shuffled the cards for all subjects?  If not, then simply test the average number of seconds among subjects with shuffled piles versus the average number of seconds among subjects with non-shuffled ones.

Otherwise, however, I think you're asking two questions here.

Question #1) *If the distribution of the ten cards is disproportionately in the first two stacks, will that affect the number of seconds it takes for a subject to identify all ten cards?*

To test this hypothesis, perhaps use a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test?  You can compare the average distribution of subjects who answered in under 130 seconds to subjects who answered in 130+ seconds. $\quad$ I doubt you'll find a significant result in your data - but I agree that a lopsided draw might affect the number of seconds: you probably won't find anything significant just because your sample is so small.

Question #2) *When you randomly shuffled the decks, are the ten cards randomly distributed into the ten piles?*

Yes,  and I think - for what you're doing - this is the more important question.  In other words, you can assume from the start that each subject had the same chance of getting a lopsided distribution... so question #1 doesn't really matter.

Comment: Yes I shuffled the cards for all subjects. No one got the same distribution. So you propose I test if the cards were randomly distributed, and if they were - I use that as argument that it didn't affect the completion times?

Comment: i think you should just assume they were randomly distributed..and use that assumption as the argument that it didn't affect completion times. :)

Comment: Well that IS my assumption, but I don't think the censors will be impressed by that argument :)

Comment: your censors sound unreasonable ;)